# Spark context wholeTextFiles ,and JavaStreamingContext textFileStream not working in Apache spark cluster

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-data-lake

I am beginner of Apache spark and Apache spark streaming programming,
        i configured to the Azure data-lake  to Apache spark using the Hadoop connector
[link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html) its connected properly and
 i can access the Adl data through terminal itself using

> hadoop fs -ls adl://xxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net

its showing list of files name contains the directory, 
but i need same list to get from program itself i tried like that

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ADL Application");     
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
JavaStreamingContext jcntxt=new JavaStreamingContext(jsc,Durations.seconds(1));     
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = jcntxt.textFileStream("adl://xxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/directory");
JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(javaDStream, "modwebservice/docs");
jcntxt.start();
jcntxt.awaitTermination();
```

but its not showing any list i tried in the "wholeTextFiles" 
instead of "textFileStream" also but its not working, and instead of directory if i use file name its working properly i can get the data also.

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);      
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
JavaStreamingContext jcntxt=new JavaStreamingContext(jsc,Durations.seconds(1));
JavaRDD<String> javaRDD6 = jsc.textFile(args[0],1);
Queue<JavaRDD<String>> microbatches = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();
microbatches.add(javaRDD6);  
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = jcntxt.queueStream(microbatches);     
JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(javaDStream, args[1]);
jcntxt.start();
jcntxt.awaitTermination();
```

and as per my knowledge Apache spark only work on local 
storage and hdfs file storage location only might be, 
i don't know how to get azure data lake directory contains file list 
i tried 2 way but its not working 
if anyone knows please share the link ,Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code below in Java to list all files on HDFS with Data Lake Store via `wholeTextFiles` method of class [`JavaSparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles(java.lang.String,%20int)) (also use the same method of [`SparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles(java.lang.String,%20int))).

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext();
String path = "adl://xxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net";
JavaPairRDD<String, String> jprdd = jsc.wholeTextFiles(String path);
for(Tuple2<String, String> tuple: jprdd.collect()) {  // Tuple2: <FileName, Content>
    System.out.println(tuple._1());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Peter ,I tried the JavaPairRDD also 
 but this line "JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(javaDStream, args[1]);"  i am getting error 
 due to unsupported saving format might be i dont know 100% whether its correct or not, if you dont mind could you guide  me how do that in proper file save format.Thank you.